# Error in Windows Forms of a form doesn´t show design view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I try to open the form in design view I got this error screen:
[image]

Then when I click ok I got another error message:
[image]

i don´t know how to fix this, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what is the problem.
When the Visual Studio has, in this case, a form with a lot of controls added, in the moment that Visual Studio try to do the rendering in design time, it simply can´t do the rendering and this error is show.
The solution is to add the controls in runtime so the Visual Studio doesn´t have to do the rendering of to many controls.

Comment: well, in one form... 25 user controls each one of them with few more controls inside

Answer (score 0):

***Generally this issue overcome when required resource for the form is missing.***

As for ex. first you have set a image to a button or any other control and then by mistake if you removed image directly from folder without setting image or background property none of that control at that time in code image is referenced that control which is not exist at that time ***designer error comes***.

This is one case for **designer error** may be in your case its different.